# Amazon DynamoDB InvalidOperationException on AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a LoadAsync to Amazon DynamoDB.

```
        var clientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig
        {
           
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
        };
        var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(clientConfig);
        var context = new DynamoDBContext(client);            
        return await context.LoadAsync<MyObject>(MyObjectIDString);
```

When I publish to Beanstalk and call the endpoint, I get an InvalidOperationException:

"Must have one hash key defined for the table MyObject"

The table exists and has values, everything works fine when executed locally from visual studio. I can see the table in the AWS console and get the appropriate objects when i execute locally.

Stacktrace:

```
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.MakeKey(Object hashKey, Object rangeKey, ItemStorageConfig storageConfig, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig)\\r\\n   
    at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.LoadHelper[T](Object hashKey, Object rangeKey, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig, Boolean isAsync)\\r\\n  
    at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.<>c__DisplayClass99_0`1.<LoadAsync>b__0()\\r\\n  

    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.AsyncRunner.<>c__DisplayClass1_2`1.<Run>b__1()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n 
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.AsyncRunner.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<<Run>b__0>d.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n 

    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   
    at Eprate.Common.DynamoLayer.DynamoLayer.<GetShow>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\\\\Users\\\\flarp\\\\Source\\\\Repos\\\\EprateGit\\\\Common\\\\DynamoLayer\\\\DynamoLayer.cs:line 38\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n 
       
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   
    at Eprate.API.Controllers.ShowController.<GetShow>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\\\\Users\\\\flarp\\\\Source\\\\Repos\\\\EprateGit\\\\API\\\\Controllers\\\\ShowController.cs:line 24",
```

Do you have any pointers as to how to investigate this? Do I need to do anything different when deployed on AWS? Something about credentials, or the IAM role maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the MyObject class, you need to have an attribute for hash key which should be annotated using `DynamoDBHashKey` annotation.

Also, you need to populate the value of the hash key before calling the load api. Basically, load api is to get the value by key attribute value.

Refer the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html) for dynamodb annotations.